# Creating a pandas dataframe from a dictionary with unique structure

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dictionary:

```
{'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Count': 'Two rebate types',
 'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': 'Credit Note',
 'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': 'July 1, 2021',
 'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': 'July 15, 2023',
 'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': 'Quarterly'}
```

As context for what I need to do is extract the first key and perform a split into two i.e.

```
CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb
```

and

```
_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection
```

I then want to create a dataframe from these values that will look like this

```
a = {'contract_id': ['CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb'],
     'Rebate-Count': ['Two rebate types'],
     'Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': ['Credit Note'],
     'Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': ['July 1, 2021'],
     'Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': ['July 15, 2023'], 
     'Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': ['Quarterly']}

df_test = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I should of specified that the dictionary does contain multiple `contract_id`.

Here is another dictionary example:

```
{'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Exists': ['Yes'],
 'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Count': [],
 'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': ['Cash Refund/Payment'],
 'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': ['July 16, 2022'],
 'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': ['July 15, 2023'],
 'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': ['Annual']}
```

Comment: I have included a second answer for cases with multiple contract_id

Comment: You still haven't provided a reproducible example with multiple contract_id. I believe the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77990121) that I provided should work in this case but cannot test it without an appropriate input. Please clarify.

Comment: I have included an second version of the second answer , that will work for the new dictionary example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dictionary_1 = {
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Count': 'Two rebate types',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': 'Credit Note',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': 'July 1, 2021',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': 'July 15, 2023',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': 'Quarterly'
}

contract_id = None
rebates_dictionary = {}

for key, value in dictionary_1.items():
    if contract_id is None:
        contract_id = key.split(".pdf_")[0]
    rebates_dictionary[key.split(".pdf_")[1]] = value

df_test = pd.DataFrame({**{"contract_id": [contract_id]}, **rebates_dictionary})

df_test
```

output:

[image]

**Solution 2 For when there is multiple contract_id_type**

```
contracts = {}
for key, value in dictionary_1.items():
    contract_id, rest = key.split(".pdf_")
    if contract_id not in contracts:
        contracts[contract_id] = {}
    contracts[contract_id][rest] = value

df_list = []    
for contract_id, rebates in contracts.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame({**{"contract_id": [contract_id]}, **rebates})
    df_list.append(df)    
    

df_test = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

df_test
```

I have tested solution 2 with another contract id i.e

```
dictionary_1 = {
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Count': 'Two rebate types',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': 'Credit Note',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': 'July 1, 2021',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': 'July 15, 2023',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': 'Quarterly',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Count': 'Two rebate types',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': 'Credit Note',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': 'July 1, 2021',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': 'July 15, 2023',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': 'Quarterly'
}
```

With that dictionary the second solution outputs:
[image]

**To Make Solution 2 Work In Cases When There Are Entries In The Dictionary Such As Your New Example**

You can replace empty lists with empty strings such as "" using

```
for key, value in dictionary_1.items():
    if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 0:
        dictionary_1[key] = ""
```

Full code with your new example dictionary:

```
dictionary_1 = {
    'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Exists': ['Yes'],
    'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Count': [],
    'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': ['Cash Refund/Payment'],
    'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': ['July 16, 2022'],
    'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': ['July 15, 2023'],
    'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': ['Annual']
}


for key, value in dictionary_1.items():
    if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 0:
        dictionary_1[key] = " "

contracts = {}
for key, value in dictionary_1.items():
    contract_id, rest = key.split(".pdf_")
    if contract_id not in contracts:
        contracts[contract_id] = {}
    contracts[contract_id][rest] = value

df_list = []    
for contract_id, rebates in contracts.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame({**{"contract_id": [contract_id]}, **rebates})
    df_list.append(df)    
    

df_test = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

df_test
```

output:
[image]

also works with the existing values of the example dictionary.
if dictionary_1 is:

```
dictionary_1 = {
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Count': 'Two rebate types',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': 'Credit Note',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': 'July 1, 2021',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': 'July 15, 2023',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': 'Quarterly',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Count': 'Two rebate types',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': 'Credit Note',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': 'July 1, 2021',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': 'July 15, 2023',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': 'Quarterly',
    'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Exists': ['Yes'],
    'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Count': [],
    'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': ['Cash Refund/Payment'],
    'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': ['July 16, 2022'],
    'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': ['July 15, 2023'],
    'Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': ['Annual']
}
```

output:
[image]

Comment: I tried this method but when I have more than one contract_id type I only get one row? Any idea why?

Comment: I coded it to work only for your task, tomorow I will edit to accomodate for possible multiple contract_id_types

Comment: @Wolfy I have included a second solution that works for cases when you have more than one contract_id_type    Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, I do have one error when I run this code
`
df_list = []    
for contract_id, rebates in contracts.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame({**{"contract_id": [contract_id]}, **rebates})
    df_list.append(df)    
`

I get this error: ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

Comment: @Wolfy , Hmm I think this issue is caused by a problem in your dictionary, when you run the dummy dictionary I create you dont recieve that error right? If you want you can e-mail me your full dictionary and I can take a look at it? cem96kocak@gmail.com

Comment: I provided a new example to the question, thank you for helping me.

Comment: @Wolfy No problem, I am happy to help, I have included a new updated version of solution 2 under solution 2 code, it will solve your errror. I have tried it myself before and after to ensure I get the same error as you and it is resolved after the inclusion of the new code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `dic` the input, I would pre-process the dictionary in a format suitable to import in [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
out = {}
for k, v in dic.items():
    k1, k2 = k.split('_', maxsplit=1)
    out.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = v

df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(out, orient='index')
        .rename_axis('contract_id').reset_index()
     )
```

Output:

```
                                                        contract_id      Rebate-Count Rebate-Spec-CashCredit Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate Rebate-Cadence-LastDate Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection
0  CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf  Two rebate types            Credit Note                   July 1, 2021           July 15, 2023                        Quarterly
```

If you can have lists of one item as values, just add a small check:

```
out = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    k1, k2 = k.split('_', maxsplit=1)
    out.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = next(iter(v), None) if isinstance(v, list) else v

df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(out, orient='index')
        .rename_axis('contract_id').reset_index()
     )
```

Output with the second example:

```
                                    contract_id Rebate-Exists Rebate-Count Rebate-Spec-CashCredit Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate Rebate-Cadence-LastDate Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection
0  Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf           Yes         None    Cash Refund/Payment                  July 16, 2022           July 15, 2023                           Annual
```

Output with @Cem's example:

```
                                                         contract_id      Rebate-Count Rebate-Spec-CashCredit Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate Rebate-Cadence-LastDate Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection Rebate-Exists
0   CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf  Two rebate types            Credit Note                   July 1, 2021           July 15, 2023                        Quarterly           NaN
1  CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf  Two rebate types            Credit Note                   July 1, 2021           July 15, 2023                        Quarterly           NaN
2                       Rebate Agreement Final (Signed Document).pdf                      Cash Refund/Payment                  July 16, 2022           July 15, 2023                           Annual           Yes
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that this needs to work on multiple contract ids, not just the example I provided.

Comment: @Wolfy can you provide an example input with multiple contract_ids? I believe my solution should work with multiple ids.

Comment: @Wolfy can you please give some feedback? As far as I can tell, this solution does what you requested and in a simple way

Comment: Hi Mozway, your solution worked but I think there may be an issue with the split as it creates multiple column I do not need, thats why I went with another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new dictionary from the original one, before creating a DataFrame with it:

```
import pandas as pd

# Original dict from OP; modified to have two ids and different values, not in order
d = {
    "CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Count": "Two rebate types",
    "CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit": "Credit Note 2",
    "CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit": "Credit Note",
    "CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate": "July 1, 2021",
    "CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate": "July 15, 2023",
    "CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection": "Quarterly",
    "CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Count": "Two rebate types 2",
    "CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate": "July 1, 2022",
    "CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate": "July 15, 2024",
    "CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection": "Quarterly 2",
}

# Create new dict
new_d = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    [id, new_k] = k.split(".pdf_")
    if id not in new_d.get("contract_id", []):
        new_d.setdefault("contract_id", []).append(id)
    index = new_d.get("contract_id").index(id)
    new_d.setdefault(new_k, []).insert(index, v)

# Define the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(new_d)
```

This will result in:

```
                                                     contract_id        Rebate-Count Rebate-Spec-CashCredit Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate Rebate-Cadence-LastDate Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection
0   CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb    Two rebate types            Credit Note                   July 1, 2021           July 15, 2023                        Quarterly
1  CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2  Two rebate types 2          Credit Note 2                   July 1, 2022           July 15, 2024                      Quarterly 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

dct = {'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Count': 'Two rebate types',
 'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': 'Credit Note',
 'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': 'July 1, 2021',
 'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': 'July 15, 2023',
 'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': 'Quarterly'}

new_dct = {}
for x,y in dct.items():
    if y == 'Two rebate types':
        id = x[:(x.find('.pdf'))]
        new_dct['contract_id'] = [id]
        break


dct2 = {x[(x.find('.pdf') + 5):] : [y] for x, y in dct.items()}
new_dct.update(dct2)

print(new_dct)
'''output:
{'contract_id': ['CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb'], 'Rebate-Count': ['Two rebate types'], 'Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': ['Credit Note'], 'Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': ['July 1, 2021'], 'Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': ['July 15, 2023'], 'Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': ['Quarterly']}
'''


df_dct = pd.DataFrame(new_dct)
print(df_dct)

'''Output:
{'contract_id': ['CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb'], 'Rebate-Count': ['Two rebate types'], 'Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': ['Credit Note'], 'Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': ['July 1, 2021'], 'Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': ['July 15, 2023'], 'Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': ['Quarterly']}
                                         contract_id  ... Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection
0  CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93e...  ...                        Quarterly

[1 rows x 6 columns]
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
d = {
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Count': 'Two rebate types',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': 'Credit Note',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': 'July 1, 2021',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': 'July 15, 2023',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': 'Quarterly',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Count': 'Two rebate types',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Spec-CashCredit': 'Credit Note',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate': 'July 1, 2021',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-LastDate': 'July 15, 2023',
    'CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93ea-96073626dccb2.pdf_Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection': 'Quarterly'
}
```

A `series` is created with the `dictionary`. The `keys` of the `dictionary` become the `index` of the `series`. A `MultiIndex` is created with this `index` which allows `unstack()` to be used.

```
((s := pd.Series(d))
.set_axis(s.index.str.rsplit('_',n=1,expand=True))
.unstack()
.reset_index(names = 'contract_id'))
```

Output:

```
contract_id Rebate-Cadence-CadenceCollection    Rebate-Cadence-First-StartDate  Rebate-Cadence-LastDate Rebate-Count    Rebate-Spec-CashCredit
0   CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93e...   Quarterly   July 1, 2021    July 15, 2023   Two rebate types    Credit Note
1   CC OTH 00009438 2023 TR.2a1e3e6f-58c4-4166-93e...   Quarterly   July 1, 2021    July 15, 2023   Two rebate types    Credit Note
```